# Can I substitute granulated sugar for caster sugar in Marzipan?

Tags: sugar

I'd like to make marzipan, but I don't have caster/superfine sugar, only "regular" white sugar. Will it work, or are there any tricks to make it work without a grinding implement?

---

I *just* finished a batch after [using a *blender* to grind up the sugar](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090426070014AAVNoWV) (the almond was already in powder form). The consistency *might* be a bit coarser, but I'm not sure I can tell the difference.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do it. Marzipan has a smooth paste consistency. Granulated sugar is not suitable, you'd end up with a preferred mixture of sugar and ... almond crumbs? Without a grinding implement, you couldn't reduce the almonds to the needed consistency either.